# Unity - move the starting position of raycast slightly forward along its direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am still new to coding in unity, so please be gentle XD ... I want to make a raycast that is hitting a collider to start a new raycast with the same direction but not starting from the point where it has hit, but just slightly forward along its direction (like a few centimeters or so, or whatever that might be in unity units ^^) ... the code snippet shows the second raycast after the first hit:

```
Physics.Raycast(firsthit.point, direction, out var hit, distance, HitLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore)
```

So I figure I need to change the "firsthit.point" value(s) somehow using the "direction", but I just cant figure out how exactly. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks, ANB_Seth

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```cs
float distance = 1f;
Vector3 newPosition = firsthit.point + direction.normalized * distance;
Physics.Raycast(newPosition, direction, out var hit, distance, HitLayerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
```